# Can I only preserve some specified file and folder structure, such as all entries, but bundling all asset files with rollup?

Tags: webpack, vite, rollup, rollupjs

I am using rollup with a hybrid framework such as RN. However, it has some specific rules for entries filepath. So, can I only preserve file and folder structure of entries and only bundling all asset files?
By the way, it is esm.